# Using Picker View to Filter CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

Right Now I'm using a `UICollectionView` extension in my code to display all my restaurant's menu items. I want to connect this to a picker view in my View controller to filter items based on the type of product. This is my code so far:

Collection View

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCells", for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionCell

        let product = products[indexPath.item]


        }

        cell.burgerName.text = product.name?.capitalized
        cell.desc.text = product.size?.capitalized
        cell.desc.textColor = UIColor.white


        if let image = product.image {
            Helpers.loadImage(cell.productImage, "\(image)")
        }

        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        return cell
    }
```

Picker View

```
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: width, height: 40)
//        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
//        view.isOpaque = true

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: width, height: 26)
        label.textAlignment = .center

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.text = sections[row]
        label.textColor = UIColor.purple
        label.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.darkText
        view.addSubview(label)

        // view rotation
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))

        return view
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        filteredProducts = self.products.filter({ (prod: Product) -> Bool in
            return prod.filter?.lowercased().range(of: UICollectionView())
        })

    }
```

I'm not sure how I should filter based the variable Section. This is another variable of the `products[indexPath.item]` called Type. So when the PickerView lands on the type, I want the collectionview to only display items with that TYPE.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: are you asking about how to filter the dataSource? or how to get the single item selected?

Comment: Filter the datasource of the CollectionView to only see items based on the PickerView. The Picker view is directly information is using a switch statement to say if "Pickerview == Breakfast" only show items with the value of "Breakfast"